# Multiple Oracle 12C Database Installation - Same Server

Tags: oracle, windows-server-2012

We are having Windows Server 2012. In that, currently Oracle 12C is up and running. The oracle related files and database files are in a Hard Drive. If in case, that drive goes down, for a backup perspective i am planning to install one more oracle 12C in the same server, but in different drive. So that, if the Primary Database is crashed, the secondary database can be used.

Is that possible to install one more Oracle 12C version, in the same server, without the disturbing the 1st instance.

Comment: What's about considering [Oracle ASM](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OSTMG/GUID-B20F761E-5217-4F49-BCB8-D200EEE5B51E.htm#OSTMG03601) to prevent from disk failure?

Comment: How will you keep the secondary DB synchronised with the primary Wouldn't it be more robust to have a completely separate server and use RAC and/or Data Guard? Or if you can really only use one server, ASM and/or RAID?

Comment: Every 3 days, at Non-Working hours, i will make a Export - Import. So that, the secondary DB will refreshed with recent data. Having a separate server, is also fine. But immediately that wont going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution, create standby database for primary database. Using archive logs standby will be refreshed automatically.